# What is difference between path and connection in iSCSI volume?

Tags: storage-area-network, iscsi, mpio

we have connected few Iscsi volumes. When we execute

> Get-IscsiConnection

it shows connection between target IP address and initiator IP address.

But when we execute

> mpclaim.exe -s -d

It shows the different values. When i enquired about this my seniors said that this is path not connection.

What is Path ? How it differs from connection?

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-IscsiConnection
```

shows (all) iSCSI **connections**

```
mpclaim
```

shows multipaths **I/O devices** (incl. iSCSI)

Get-iSCSISession showing the exact connection, but not the MPIO policy which is used for iSCSI volume. By executing - mpclaim.exe -s -d you can find out the Load Balance Policy, and a number of the system disk. If you will specify needed Disk, you will see how many paths are active/standby, active/active or active/optimized.